# What purpose of this op amp in Conductivity probe circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I try to understand this schematic.

My understand, left op-amp as buffer stage. 
But what is purpose capacitor C2, gate S of MOSFET connect to GPIO of MCU, the second op-amp.

Diode D1 and D2 protect to input conductivity probe?

Op-amp [TL062](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl062a.pdf)

MOSFET [2N7002](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/2N7002-8405.pdf)

Sorry for my English is bad. :)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The right-hand op amp is inverting op amp with Av = -1. So input probe is -1.2V? This's right?

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand opamp provides a buffered DC bias voltage to the MOSFET (and C2), through a source impedance set by R2.

Since C2 blocks DC between the two halves of the circuit, there must be an AC signal involved. The only possible source of such a signal would be the `GPIO_MCU` connection, coupled through the source-gate capacitance of the MOSFET.

This signal is filtered by R3 and C3, then inverted by the right-hand opamp (as configured by R4 and R5).

The inductor and diodes are there to protect the opamp by clamping any transient signals (such as ESD) that might be applied to the `probe` terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So why I needed an AC signal into input `probe` terminal?

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea. Where did you get the circuit, and what is its intended application?

Comment: I want to build circuit read value of conductivity sensor.

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific than that. **Where did you get the circuit?** You obviously didn't design it yourself, or you would already know how it works. And **what conductivity sensor?** Be specific, and provide a link to a datasheet.

Comment: [CS150 Probe](https://sensorex.com/product/cs150tc-tds-conductivity-probe/?nabe=4869876582973440:0,5432826536394752:0,5457303796187136:0,5656007532609536:1,6309734237077504:0,6748276771782656:0) I was a conductivity circuit. So I redraw the circuit. I have read [reference design](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/hardware-reference-design/circuits-from-the-lab/CN0359.html#rd-sampleproducts) but it's have a lot of IC and I must be ship in US to my country.